Basics of strength of material
What if the load applied is neither axial nor on transverse axis  but some random point on a beam/pipe ?

Eccentric load with inclination.

One will generally apply superposition on an element- ie forces at a point sum together. This is what FEA does with tiny elements. You can do FEA on paper too, just might be slower. Simplest and least accurate case is that of one element... Ultimately the basics are that you will either achieve equilibrium or accelerate.

A what if question is vague. Is this about deflection? Bending or torque? Is this about movement? What have you done so far to set up and explore the different approaches?

It is about bending

In general you need to transfer this load into equivalent load on the axis. The point of application $P$ lies on a beam section perpendicular to its axis. In case of a force $\overrightarrow{F_P}$, the same force vector will act on the point $A$ where this section intersects axis and in addition to that, there will also be a moment $\overrightarrow{M_A}$ acting on the axis, because the original force $\overrightarrow{F_P}$ acts on lever arm $\overrightarrow{AP}$ with respect to the axis:
$$\overrightarrow{M_A} = \overrightarrow{AP}\times\overrightarrow{F_P}$$
If a moment $\overrightarrow{M_P}$ acts on a point $P$, the same moment also acts on the corresponding (on the same section) point $A$ at the axis.

Any force $ \ F \ $ applied to a beam or rigid object should be resolved into its axial, $F*cos(a), \  $and normal, $ \ F *sin(a)$ projections.
The axial projection is the colinear force and the normal projection will cause a moment.
Edit
Answering the OP comment.
If the load $F$ axial projection is offset from the centerline of the beam by, say, a distance $\delta \ $. This offset causes another moment$ \ M_{\delta}$.
$$M_{\delta}=\delta*F*cos (a)$$
This moment is added to the moment caused by $Fsin(a).$
.

'


But in this case what to do if the applied force is at a random point on the circular surace area and not at an axial point?

@PrithuBharadwaj I edited the answer; check it.

Thank you @Kamran
